# Angular 6, UI not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, model-view-controller

I am using MVC with Angular 6. I have my angular code compiled with no errors on the console but the HTML UI is not getting displayed.
The screen is blang with "Loading.." text from the Index.html The Angulat component HTML is not rendered.

if I comment the  'typescript': './node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js', from the System.config.js,

I get

```
  `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not 
   Found)
 localhost/:46 Error: Fetch error: 404 Not Found
 Instantiating http://localhost:26137/typescript
 Loading typescript
 Unable to load transpiler to transpile 
 http://localhost:26137/node_modules/rxjs/rx.js
 Instantiating http://localhost:26137/node_modules/rxjs/rx.js
Loading 
 http://localhost:26137/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js
 Loading app
   at system.src.js:1454
  at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
  at Zone.run (zone.js:138)
  at zone.js:872
  at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
  at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
  at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
  at n (shim.min.js:8)
  `at shim.min.js:8
 at MutationObserver.t (shim.min.js:7)
(anonymous) @ localhost/:46
```

My System.config.js

```
  /**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
  */
(function (global) {
System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions:
        {
            emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
            experimentalDecorators: true
        },
    paths: {
        // paths serve as alias
        'npm:': './node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
        // our app is within the app folder
        'app': './app',

        // angular bundles
        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        //'@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
        '@angular/common/http': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
        'tslib': 'npm:tslib/tslib.js',
        'typescript': './node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js',
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
        'rxjs-compat': 'npm:rxjs-compat',
        'rxjs-system-bundle': 'npm:rxjs-system-bundle',
        'rxjs-bundle': ['rxjs/*', 'rxjs/observable/*', 'rxjs/operator/*', 'rxjs/subject/*'],
        'core-js': 'npm:core-js',
        'zone.js': 'npm:zone.js',
        /*'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'*/
        'igniteui-angular': 'npm:igniteui-angular',
        'igniteui-angular-wrappers': 'npm:igniteui-angular-wrappers'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
        app: {
            main: 'main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            meta: {
                './*.js': {
                    loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
                }
            }
        },
        //rxjs: {
        //    defaultExtension: 'js'
        //},
        rxjs: {
            main: 'rx',
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            format: 'esm'
        },
        "rxjs/operators": {
            "main": "index.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },

        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'igniteui-angular-wrappers': {
            main: 'igniteui.angular2.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'igniteui-angular': {
            main: 'main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },           
        bundles: {
            // note: the inject:bundles comment below is used as a marker for the build script, do not remove
            // inject:bundles
        }
    }
});
})(this);
```

My Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "elployee-call-audit-client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build",``
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
 "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
  "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
  "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
  "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
  "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
  "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
  "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
  "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
  "core-js": "^2.5.6",
  "es6-shim": "^0.35.3",
 "igniteui-angular": "6.0.0",
 "igniteui-angular-wrappers": "5.1.1",
 "rxjs": "6.2.0",
 "rxjs-compat": "6.2.0",
 "rxjs-system-bundle": "^6.0.0",
 "systemjs": "0.21.3",
 "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.3",
  "typescript": "~2.8.3",
  "@angular/cli": "~6.0.3",
  "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
  "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.7",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
  "@types/node": "~10.1.2",
 "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
 "jasmine-core": "~3.1.0",
 "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
 "karma": "~2.0.2",
 "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
 "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
 "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
 "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.1.0",
 "protractor": "~5.3.2",
 "ts-node": "~6.0.5",
 "tslint": "~5.10.0"
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until no code can be removed while still running into the problem?

Comment: I have tried all means. But now I moved all my code to Angular CLI from .NET MVC. Now I am able to get proper errors displayed in the Developer tools console which is helping me to move forward while same code doesn't compile in Visual Studio.